# php amazon s3 bucket creation

Tags: php, amazon-s3

We try to create a bucket on Amazon S3............. what's wrong with this code????????????

```
$req =& new HTTP_Request("http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket-name]"); 
$req->setMethod("PUT"); 
setAuthorizationHeader($req); 
$req->sendRequest(); 

if ($req->getResponseCode() == 200)
{     
    // bucket was created 
} 
else 
{     
    // something bad happened 
}
```

Comment: I assume `HTTP_Request` is `pear/HTTP_Request` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [Pear implementation of an S3 Client](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Amazon_S3/) as a reference (it's still in alpha)